# How many different 3D parallelepiped are in 4D hyper-parallelepiped?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperspace

Let's say I have three 3D linearly independent vectors, these vectors form a parallelepiped. This parallelepiped has 6 faces, but only 3 of them are "unique" (the other three can be obtained as reflections with $xy$, $yz$ and $xz$).

My question is, what is the rule that defines how many unique faces are in a $n-$dimensional parallelepiped? For instance, a 4D hyper-parallelepiped how many unique 3D parallelepiped would contain?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you specify a "unique" $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelepiped by saying which of the $n$ vectors _isn't_ used to make it.

Comment: Well that makes sense, but how do I treat the "remaining" dimension? I mean, the vectors are in 4 dimensions, but I am trying to find a 3D figure

Comment: Translating one $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelepiped parallel to the vector it doesn't use takes it to a congruent $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelepiped. (By the way, I should probably instead call it a _parallelotope_, although _parallelepiped_ is also used.)

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you very much!

Comment: One last question, if I can! What about the number of different 2D faces (for example, a 3d parallelotope has 3 unique faces) - Since a lot of the 24 faces are obtained by symmetries

Comment: More generally, the number of different kinds of $k$-parallelotopes in an $n$-parallelotope [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}{k}$; see if you can figure out why.

Comment: So, it's the number of combinations that I can make with $k$ vectors in a $n$ space! Perhaps I am getting it but, sorry, how could I "draw" these $k$-parallelotopes? I mean, in order to draw all the different 2D faces in a 4-parallelotope I should take pairs of vectors, but which axes should I drop each time?

Comment: To be honest the only diagrammatic option I can suggest for $k=2$ is to keep drawing parallelograms whose sides are labelled so as to imply they're whichever pair of vectors that diagram is for. You may wish to practice this with $n=3$. You can similarly handle $k=3$ by drawing parallelepipeds.